# numeric sort a list of strings in R

Tags: r

I have a list:

```
a <- ["12file.txt", "8file.txt", "66file.txt"]
```

I would like to sort by number:

```
a would be: ["8file.txt", "12file.txt", "66file.txt"]
```

Now I could get only this:

```
a = ["12file.txt", "66file.txt", "8file.txt"]
```

Thanks

Comment: do you mean `c("12file.txt" `... or `list("12file.txt"`...? Because `["12file.txt"`... isn't either

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm assuming you have a character vector:

```
a <- c("12file.txt", "8file.txt", "66file.txt")
```

I would approach this by pulling out the number at the start of each string and sorting on that:

```
num <- as.numeric(sub("([0-9]+).*", "\\1", a))
a[order(num)]
#[1] "8file.txt"  "12file.txt" "66file.txt"
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also pad your strings with spaces by setting a field length to `sprintf` to achieve the sorting you want:

```
a[order(sprintf("%10s",a))]
[1] "8file.txt"  "12file.txt" "66file.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str_sort(..., numeric = TRUE)` function from `stringr` package:

```
library(stringr)
a <- c("12file.txt", "8file.txt", "66file.txt")

str_sort(a, numeric = TRUE)
#> [1] "8file.txt"  "12file.txt" "66file.txt"
```